# Solving coupled PDEs using NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Im very new to Mathematica and trying to solve a model of two PDEs. The system contains two components that get generated after T=0.5 and diffuse away and dissapear at either end (If I've described it correctly). I've tried the below, getting the following error.

> Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.

Any help with this would be appreciated! Thanks.

````
De = 1 * 10^-13;
Dh = 1 * 10^-19;
a = 1 * 10^ 5;
krec = 10^3;
kc = 10^3;
Ibase = 10^-3;
I0[x_, t_] := Ibase * If[t < 0.5, 0, 1];

xmin = 0;
xmax = 1*10^-6;
Tmin = 0;
Tmax = 2;

eqn11 = D[El[x, t], t] == 
   a*I0  + De*D[El[x, t], x, x] - krec*El[x, t]*H[x, t];
eqn21 = D[H[x, t], t] == 
   a*I0 + Dh*D[H[x, t], x, x] - krec*El[x, t]*H[x, t] - kc*H[x, t];
ic2 = H[x, Tmin] == 0
ic1 = El[x, Tmin] == 0;

NDSolveValue[{eqn11, eqn21, ic2, ic1, 
  Derivative[1, 0][El][xmax, t] == 0, El[xmin, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][H][xmin, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][H][xmax, t] == -kc*H[xmax, t]}, {El, H}, {x, xmin, 
  xmax}, {t, Tmin, Tmax}]
```
````

Comment: Check your equations: `I0` is used as a parameter and as a function `I0[x, t]`!